# Yum install can't find perf library

Tags: linux, redhat, perf

I am trying `yum install perf`([this tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux))), but I get:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package perf available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

My OS details: `Linux version 2.6.32`, `Red Hat 4.4.5-6` (as read from `/proc/version`).

I also tried `yum install linux-tools` with no success. The webpage I linked says that this should be available starting from `2.6.31` kernel version, but it's not!

Is there anything I could do about it or some alternative I can use?

Comment: Wrong site. Not a programming question.

Comment: This does need to get moved to another site though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that most of the default CentOS repos were disabled in the repos list on the server I was using. You can check the status of repos running `yum repolist all`.

Then running `yum-config-manager --enable C6*` enables all repos with ids starting with C6. That fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 4 is [really old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#Product_life_cycle) and its kernel does not support perf as written in your linked wikipedia article

> Perf is natively supported in many popular Linux distributions, including Red Hat Enterprise Linux (since its version 6 released in 2010).